# App crashes using intent with table layout

Tags: android, android-intent, runtimeexception

Trying to make it so when I go to a page it creates a table. When I do the transfer to the page without the table it works, and when I have the table just by itself, it works fine, but when I combine the two, it just crashes with an `AndroidRuntime error`... Here is my code:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //setContentView(R.layout.activity);

    Intent i = getIntent();
    createTable();

}

public void createTable(){
     setContentView(R.layout.activity);
     TableLayout lo = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.displayLinear);

     TableRow headerRow = new TableRow(this);
     TableRow.LayoutParams hp = new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
     headerRow.setLayoutParams(hp);
     tv = new TextView(this);
     tv.setText("Text Header");
     headerRow.addView(tv);
     lo.addView(headerRow);

        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {

            TableRow row= new TableRow(this);
            TableRow.LayoutParams lp = new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            row.setLayoutParams(lp);
            checkBox = new CheckBox(this);
            tv = new TextView(this);
            qty = new TextView(this);
            checkBox.setText("hello");
            qty.setText("10");
            row.addView(checkBox);
            row.addView(qty);
            lo.addView(row,i);
        }
 }
```

Logcat:

```
07-28 10:17:13.400: E/AndroidRuntime(10363): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-28 10:17:13.400: E/AndroidRuntime(10363): Process: cooper.tirerfid, PID: 10363
07-28 10:17:13.400: E/AndroidRuntime(10363): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{cooper.tirerfid/cooper.tirerfid.AllTiresActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-28 10:17:13.400: E/AndroidRuntime(10363):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2235)
07-28 10:17:13.400: E/AndroidRuntime(10363):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2285)
07-28 10:17:13.400: E/AndroidRuntime(10363):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:138)
07-28 10:17:13.400: E/AndroidRuntime(10363):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1236)
07-28 10:17:13.400: E/AndroidRuntime(10363):    at    android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
07-28 10:17:13.400: E/AndroidRuntime(10363):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:149)
07-28 10:17:13.400: E/AndroidRuntime(10363):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5061)
07-28 10:17:13.400: E/AndroidRuntime(10363):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-28 10:17:13.400: E/AndroidRuntime(10363):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
07-28 10:17:13.400: E/AndroidRuntime(10363):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:788)
07-28 10:17:13.400: E/AndroidRuntime(10363):    at     com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:604)
07-28 10:17:13.400: E/AndroidRuntime(10363):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-28 10:17:13.400: E/AndroidRuntime(10363): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-28 10:17:13.400: E/AndroidRuntime(10363):    at cooper.tirerfid.AllTiresActivity.createTable(AllTiresActivity.java:90)
07-28 10:17:13.400: E/AndroidRuntime(10363):    at cooper.tirerfid.AllTiresActivity.onCreate(AllTiresActivity.java:30)
07-28 10:17:13.400: E/AndroidRuntime(10363):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5387)
07-28 10:17:13.400: E/AndroidRuntime(10363):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
07-28 10:17:13.400: E/AndroidRuntime(10363):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2199)
```

When I step through it, it errors out at this line:
     `lo.addView(headerRow);`

XML file:

```
<TableLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:background="#C0C0C0"  >

<!-- Once the column headers are known go back into the string.xml file and add them to elimiate     warnings -->

<TableRow
  android:background="#C0C0C0" >
<TextView android:text="RFID"
    android:layout_width="100dp"        
    android:layout_column="0"
    android:layout_weight="1"/>
<TextView android:text="Number"
    android:layout_width="30dp"
    android:layout_column="1"
    android:layout_weight="1">
</TextView>
<TextView android:text="Yes/No"
    android:layout_width="30dp"
    android:layout_column="2"
    android:layout_weight="1">
</TextView>
</TableRow>
<ScrollView android:layout_height="fill_parent">      
<TableLayout android:id="@+id/displayLinear"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:background="#C0C0C0"  >          
<TableRow>
    <TextView android:text="Al"
    android:layout_width="100dp"        
    android:layout_column="0"
    android:layout_weight="1">
    </TextView>
    <TextView android:text="1000"
    android:layout_width="30dp"
    android:layout_column="1"
    android:layout_weight="1">
    </TextView>
    <TextView android:text="2"
    android:layout_width="30dp"
    android:layout_column="2"
    android:layout_weight="1">
    </TextView>
    </TableRow>
  </TableLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: why are  you using setContentView(R.layout.activity); twice?

Comment: `getIntent` is how you receive an intent that is sent from another page

Comment: I took out `setContentView(R.layout.activity)` so it's not in there twice

Comment: What is on your line 90? (AllTiresActivity.java:90)

Comment: lo.addView(headerRow);

Comment: Can you post the layout XML?

Comment: Posted it for you guys, my bad

Comment: Are you sure that the view is being set correctly? What happens if you don't do anything after setContentView()?

Answer (score 2):

Based on the code that you posted and the logcat data, the only possibility that I can see is that

```
TableLayout lo = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.displayLinear);
```

returned null. Are you sure that `R.layout.activity` has an item with an ID of `displayLinear`? It would help if you posted your activity.xml file.

When you step through the code, what is the value of `lo` after calling `findViewById()`?

Edit:
The XML that you posted cannot possibly compile. You have 2 TableLayout opening tags but only one TableLayout closing tags. Looks like you may have copy/pasted something in the wrong place.

Comment: Yes It is returning `null`

Comment: I have an `id` in the layout file with that name though

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the TableLayout is not found therfore `findViewById()` is returning a  null pointer , try some of these:

- Clean the project via Project -> Clean... -> check your project -> OK
- Ensure you have absolutely no spelling errors in the ID
- Make sure the contentView is displaying the correct layout where the `TableLayout` exists
- Make sure you `setContentView` before `findViewById`

I'm assuming the 3rd option I've listed is most likely your problem.

Re-cleaning the project may also help after each of these steps.